# Removing animation name after completion

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to remove the animation name after it's completed. This is my code.
I think that there is a problem in my jquery, but I can't seem to find it.

css

```
.nonlivemessage {
opacity: 0;
display: inline-block;
color: red;
font-weight: 600;
animation: 0.5s ease-in 0s normal both;
margin-top: 15px;
background-color: red;
color: white;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 5px 3px;
}

@keyframes nonlive {

    0%{ 
    opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
    opacity: 1;
    }   

    100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }

}
```

jquery

```
<script>
    $(window).on("load", function() {

    $( ".nonlivebutton" ).click(function() {
      $(".nonlivemessage").css("animation-name", "nonlive"), function(){
            $(".nonlivemessage").css("animation-name", "none");

        } 
    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove none from $(".nonlivemessage").css("animation-name", "none");
$(window).on("load", function() {

```
$( ".nonlivebutton" ).click(function() {
  $(".nonlivemessage").css("animation-name", "nonlive"), function(){
        $(".nonlivemessage").css("animation-name", "");

    } 
});
```

Comment: Hi Ram, Thanks for the info, but nonlive isn't a class, its an animation-name. Also, I only want to remove the nonlive animation-name after it's finished, not on click.

Comment: i've changed my answer

Comment: Hi Ram, Sorry. This code doesn't work. The animation name remains on nonlivemessage.